# Get SpringSecurityService in plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, javabeans

How I get the service springSecurityService bean in a own plugin?

I tried this, but i don't now if this is the correct strategy.

> def doWithSpring = {
>   springSecurityService(application.mainContext.getBean('springSecurityService'))
>
> }

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

If attempting to use it from a service or controller in the plugin, you can simply use

```
def springSecurityService
```

as a member variable in the groovy class. Since this is purely a runtime dependency, your plugin does not have to depend directly on the Spring Security Plugin. However, if your plugin is ever used in an application that does not make the Spring Security Plugin available at runtime, this will fail for obvious reasons.

Also important to note: this is true for any Grails service, not just the Spring Security Service.

Comment: But i need to use this in a Groovy class.

Comment: A Groovy class inside of a Grails application? How exactly is this Groovy class being used?

Comment: A groovy class inside a grails plugin.

Comment: That does not clarify at all. Is it a Grails-specific groovy class (i.e. - Service, Controller, TagLib, Script, etc.)?

Comment: Sorry, is stored in src/groovy

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this method will *not* work from an arbitrary Groovy class in the application. That being said, I'm not sure what you would be doing in an arbitrary Groovy class with the Spring Security Service. Can you please edit your question and post a snippet of code related to how you intend to use the service?